# How to serialize beautifulsoup access-paths?

Tags: python, html, parsing, serialization, beautifulsoup

i have code, which does something like this:

```
item.previous.parent.parent.aTag['href']
```

now i would like to be able to add filters fast, so hardcoding is no longer an option. how can i access the same tags with a path coded in a string?

of course i could invent some format like [('getattr', 'previous'), ('getattr', 'parent'), ..., ('getitem', 'href)] and parse it with __getattr__ and __getitem__.

Now the question: Is there already a more beautiful way of doing it, or do i need to implement it myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that you would be better off using a XPATH expression. This [discussion](http://groups.google.com/group/beautifulsoup/browse_thread/thread/d416dd19fdaa43a6) has some information about an XPATH plugin for BeautifulSoup called BSXPath. I haven't used it so I do not know if it will serve your purpose.

If you are willing to replace BeautifulSoup then [lxml](http://codespeak.net/lxml/) has a really powerful XPATH implementation.

**update**

See [@llasram](https://stackoverflow.com/users/333504/llasram)'s comment to this answer:

> These days lxml has an html module which the BeautifulSoup implementer himself recommends over BeautifulSoup. It even has a soupparser sub-module which will use BeautifulSoup to do the parsing!

Comment: i thought about xpath, but the cool thing about beautifulsoup is, that i do not need to rely on correct and stable html, but can parse anything that looks like html.

Comment: @allo: valid point. I think in that case you will have to implement it yourself.

Comment: These days lxml has an `html` module which the BeautifulSoup implementer himself recommends over BeautifulSoup.  It even has a `soupparser` sub-module which will use BeautifulSoup to do the parsing!